# Is MVC Web Application upgrade required to support SameSite cookie in New version of Crome Browser

Tags: samesite

I am using VS2015 .NetFramework4.5.2 to develop web application using repository pattern and used Session.
I am not using any Azure App Services, Web API and Used ASP.NET Identity Management for login.
So i am not using the below Web.Config settings
AppSettings section

```
<add key="aspnet:SuppressSameSiteNone" value="true" />
```

System.web section

`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25" cookieSameSite="None" ></sessionState>`**

Do i need to upgrade my web application to .NetFramework version 4.7.2 to support new version(version 80) of Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

The new `SameSite=None; Secure` attributes which will be required by Chrome, Edge, and Firefox are **only** intended for cookies that are needed in third-party or cross-site contexts. If you only need to use your cookies when your user is on your site, then this is just first-party. You can either set `SameSite=Lax` or `SameSite=Strict`, or just leave the cookies as is.

If you **do** need cross-site / third-party access then you should ideally update to the latest version, however the ASP.NET team has also pointed to some options if you cannot upgrade: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/